# Cannot fetch the authentity token from AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, token, amazon-cognito

I want to fetch the authentication tokens from AWS;
however, I only receive an error telling me
that the client id is not correct.

I was very happy to have found this code on the web,
link: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/authentication.html
and I was able to invoke the last function call,
but it complains about the ClientId, and I have no clue
where to fetch the Clientid from :-(

I am not sure from where to fetch the Client Id and User Pool Id from?

There is also a Client App Id on the AWS web site.

I am looking for something where I only have to provide
the userid and password using node js?

---

const AmazonCognitoIdentity = require('amazon-cognito-identity-js');

var authenticationData = {
Username : '...',
Password : '...',
};

```
var authenticationDetails = new AmazonCognitoIdentity.AuthenticationDetails(authenticationData);

var poolData = { 
    UserPoolId : '...', // From where on the AWS web site can I fetch the correct User Pool Id?
    ClientId : '...' // From where on the AWS web site can I fetch the correct client Id?
};

var userPool = new AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoUserPool(poolData);

var userData = {
    Username : 'karlschmitt',
    Pool : userPool
};

var cognitoUser = new AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoUser(userData);

   
cognitoUser.authenticateUser(authenticationDetails, {
    onSuccess: function (result) {
        var accessToken = result.getAccessToken().getJwtToken();

        /* Use the idToken for Logins Map when Federating User 
        Pools with identity pools or when passing through an 
        Authorization Header to an API Gateway Authorizer */
        var idToken = result.idToken.jwtToken;
        console. log("Successful!");
    },

    onFailure: function(err) {
        // alert(err);
        console. log("Failure!" + err.message);
    },

});
```

Answer (score 0):

- Create Congnito User Pool - [Here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pool-as-user-directory.html) is a link and grab `Pool Id` from General Settings
- Register your application as a Client - [Here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-settings-client-apps.html) is a link and grab `client id`